# Paypal sandbox stop working?

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, paypal-sandbox

Currently I'm testing my store using paypal sandbox with PayPal Payments Standard. It's working fine yesterday but when I try to test it again today I receive a bunch of error messages from paypal after clicking "Pay" button(I'm using Pay with my debit or credit card option):

> ConnectionManagerError: Cannot connect to db FININST, pip
>   fininst_occ_host 1:10.72.108.212:33465: connection refused. Gave up
>   after 2 ConnectionManager tries. Backtrace:
>   PPException::PPException(String const&)
>   ConnectionManagerError::ConnectionManagerError(String const&)
>   ConnectionManager::connect_pip(SmartPointer const&, OCCHost const&,
>   unsigned) ConnectionManager::get_connection(OCCHost const&, bool,
>   bool, bool) TransactionHandler::prepare_sql(char const*, OCCHost
>   const&, char const*, unsigned, bool) BaseDB::prepare_sql(char const*,
>   char const*, unsigned, bool) CachingBaseDB::prepare_sql(char const*,
>   BaseDBString::ASCIIString const&, bool)
>   WUserCC::load_by_cc_number_with_closed(String const&, unsigned long,
>   unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long)
>   FinancialInstrument::CreditCardPBImpl::load_by_cc_number(String
>   const&, TArray&, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned
>   long) const
>   FinancialInstrument::CreditCardSCPBImpl::load_by_cc_number(String
>   const&, TArray&, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned
>   long) const
>   FinancialInstrument::CreditCardBLIImpl::get_cc_list_by_cc_number_hash(String
>   const&, TArray&, TArray const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned
>   long, unsigned long)
>   Merchant::PimpWAXBLIImpl::analyze_user_cc_commit(PimpWAXAnalyzeUser
>   const&, PimpUser&, PimpCC&, unsigned long long&, unsigned long long&,
>   PimpCCTransResult*, bool*, bool)
>   Merchant::PimpAutoWAXBLIImpl::wax_analyze_user_cc(PimpWAXAnalyzeUser
>   const&, PimpUser&, PimpCC&, unsigned long long&, unsigned long long&,
>   PimpCCTransResult*, bool)
>   Rapids::BusinessBlocks::wax_create_new_user(PayPalCommonWebAppContext
>   const&, unsigned long long, String const&, unsigned long long&,
>   unsigned long long&, PimpAddress&, BuyerInfoUbiquityContainer&, String
>   const&, SignUpUbiquityContainer&, unsigned long long&, unsigned long
>   long&, unsigned long const&, PimpCC&, PimpTransaction&, bool)
>   Rapids::BusinessBlocks::wax_create_new_user(PayPalCommonWebAppContext
>   const&, unsigned long long, String&, unsigned long long&, unsigned
>   long long&, PimpAddress&, BuyerInfoUbiquityContainer&,
>   MerchantInfoUbiquityContainer&, SignUpUbiquityContainer&,
>   FundingUbiquityContainer&, TransactionUbiquityContainer&,
>   TaxAndShippingUbiquityContainer&, PimpCC&, PimpTransaction&, bool)
>   Rapids::Flows::Unity::StateUnityValidateCCandBC::execute(Rapids::CGIVars
>   const&) Rapids::DecoratedState::execute(Rapids::CGIVars const&)
>   Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::handle_execute(Riprap::WebAppContextOrnate
>   const&, Rapids::TransitionRegistry const&, Rapids::State*, String
>   const&, String const&, unsigned long long)
>   Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::process_states(Riprap::WebAppContextOrnate
>   const&, Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::ProcessStates,
>   Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&, Rapids::TransitionEdge
>   const*)
>   Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::flow_continue_post(Riprap::WebAppContextOrnate
>   const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&)
>   Riprap::call_rapids(Riprap::WebAppContext const&,
>   Riprap::RapidsFlowFactory const&, Riprap::DispatchAction const&,
>   Riprap::WebAppReturn const&, String const&,
>   Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&)
>   Riprap::dispatch_loop(Riprap::EPRegistry const&, Riprap::WebAppContext
>   const&, Riprap::DispatchAction&, Riprap::WebAppReturn&, String const&,
>   Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&)
>   Riprap::dispatch_wrapper(OutputStream&, Riprap::EPRegistry const&,
>   Riprap::WebAppContext const&, Riprap::WebAppReturn const&, String
>   const&, bool const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&)
>   Riprap::entry_point(HTTPInterface&, Riprap::CGIVars&, OutputStream&,
>   String const&, String const&) main
>
> An error has occurred.

Is there something wrong with my part or above messages are some serious mistakes coming from Paypal itself?

Comment: They may update something in their side, in the process you receive some error i hope, i too face the same problem couple of hours before, now i can able to perform payment in sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and solved it by clearing the cache using CCleaner for ALL Browsers, and tried a different browser, as suggested in other posts.